# Unsupported extension type after upgrading Spring Boot + WebFlux + MongoDB app from 2.3 to 2.4

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I'm trying to [upgrade JHipster to use Spring Boot 2.4](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/13551). I created an app with Spring WebFlux and MongoDB and there are a few tests that fail in `PlaceResourceIT.java`. For example, the `getPlace()` test.

```java
@Test
void getPlace() {
    // Initialize the database
    placeRepository.save(place).block();

    // Get the place
    webTestClient
        .get()
        .uri("/api/places/{id}", place.getId())
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus()
        .isOk()
        .expectHeader()
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .expectBody()
        .jsonPath("$.id")
        .value(is(place.getId()))
        .jsonPath("$.name")
        .value(is(DEFAULT_NAME))
        .jsonPath("$.numberOfSeats")
        .value(is(DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_SEATS.intValue()))
        .jsonPath("$.shortName")
        .value(is(DEFAULT_SHORT_NAME))
        .jsonPath("$.colorBackground")
        .value(is(DEFAULT_COLOR_BACKGROUND))
        .jsonPath("$.colorText")
        .value(is(DEFAULT_COLOR_TEXT))
        .jsonPath("$.description")
        .value(is(DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION.toString()));
}
```

The error is:

```
2021-01-22 13:24:15.670 ERROR 702 --- [oundedElastic-1] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Internal Server Error

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported extension type: org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension@6e774194
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ReactiveExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.lambda$getExtensions$4(ReactiveExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:149)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Flux.concatMap(Flux.java:3626)
    org.springframework.data.spel.ReactiveExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.getExtensions(ReactiveExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:118)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_      Flux.concatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.data.spel.ReactiveExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.getExtensions(ReactiveExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:118)
    |_    Flux.collectList ⇢ at org.springframework.data.spel.ReactiveExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.getExtensions(ReactiveExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:150)
    |_            Mono.map ⇢ at org.springframework.data.spel.ReactiveExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.getEvaluationContextLater(ReactiveExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:109)
    |_       Mono.doOnNext ⇢ at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ReactiveExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider.getEvaluationContextLater(ReactiveExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider.java:134)
    |_           Mono.cast ⇢ at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ReactiveExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider.getEvaluationContextLater(ReactiveExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider.java:136)
    |_            Mono.map ⇢ at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractReactiveMongoQuery.getSpelEvaluatorFor(AbstractReactiveMongoQuery.java:278)
    |_ Mono.defaultIfEmpty ⇢ at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractReactiveMongoQuery.getSpelEvaluatorFor(AbstractReactiveMongoQuery.java:280)
    |_            Mono.map ⇢ at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ReactiveStringBasedMongoQuery.getBindingContext(ReactiveStringBasedMongoQuery.java:150)
    |_            Mono.map ⇢ at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ReactiveStringBasedMongoQuery.lambda$createQuery$3(ReactiveStringBasedMongoQuery.java:126)
    |_        Mono.zipWith ⇢ at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ReactiveStringBasedMongoQuery.lambda$createQuery$3(ReactiveStringBasedMongoQuery.java:130)
    |_            Mono.map ⇢ at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ReactiveStringBasedMongoQuery.lambda$createQuery$3(ReactiveStringBasedMongoQuery.java:130)
    |_        Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ReactiveStringBasedMongoQuery.createQuery(ReactiveStringBasedMongoQuery.java:123)
    |_    Mono.flatMapMany ⇢ at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractReactiveMongoQuery.doExecute(AbstractReactiveMongoQuery.java:148)
    |_      Flux.usingWhen ⇢ at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$ReactiveInvocationListenerDecorator.decorate(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:242)
    |_           Mono.from ⇢ at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrapperConverters$PublisherToMonoConverter.convert(ReactiveWrapperConverters.java:564)
    |_  Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ at tech.jhipster.web.util.reactive.ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(ResponseUtil.java:36)
    |_            Mono.map ⇢ at tech.jhipster.web.util.reactive.ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(ResponseUtil.java:37)
    |_        Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ResponseEntityResultHandler.handleResult(ResponseEntityResultHandler.java:128)
    |_          checkpoint ⇢ Handler tech.jhipster.sample.web.rest.PlaceResource#getPlace(String) [DispatcherHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.data.spel.ReactiveExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.lambda$getExtensions$4(ReactiveExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:149)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:374)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:218)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046)
```

The method that's called is as follows:

```java
/**
 * {@code GET  /places/:id} : get the "id" place.
 *
 * @param id the id of the place to retrieve.
 * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 200 (OK)} and with body the place, or with status {@code 404 (Not Found)}.
 */
@GetMapping("/places/{id}")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Place>> getPlace(@PathVariable String id) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Place : {}", id);
    Mono<Place> place = placeRepository.findOneWithEagerRelationships(id);
    return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(place);
}
```

The `PlaceRepository` interface looks as follows:

```java
package tech.jhipster.sample.repository;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import tech.jhipster.sample.domain.Place;

/**
 * Spring Data MongoDB reactive repository for the Place entity.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface PlaceRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Place, String> {
    @Query("{}")
    Flux<Place> findAllWithEagerRelationships(Pageable pageable);

    @Query("{}")
    Flux<Place> findAllWithEagerRelationships();

    @Query("{'id': ?0}")
    Mono<Place> findOneWithEagerRelationships(String id);
}
```

If I regenerate the app with JHipster 7 beta 1 (which uses Spring Boot 2.3), everything works.

I [uploaded the project to GitHub](https://github.com/mraible/webflux-mongodb) so you can reproduce the error. Just clone it and run `./mvnw verify`.

```
git clone https://github.com/mraible/webflux-mongodb.git
cd webflux-mongodb
./mvnw verify
```

You'll get the following errors:

```
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   PlaceResourceIT.getAllPlaces:219 Status expected:<200 OK> but was:<500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR>
[ERROR]   PlaceResourceIT.getNonExistingPlace:298 Status expected:<404 NOT_FOUND> but was:<500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR>
[ERROR]   PlaceResourceIT.getPlace:269 Status expected:<200 OK> but was:<500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR>
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 109, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

You can see that it works with Spring Boot 2.3 with the following steps in the `webflux-mongodb` directory:

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster@beta
rm -rf * # this keeps dot files, so .yo-rc.json and .jhipster will still be intact
jhipster --with-entities # select a when prompted to overwrite
./mvnw verify
```

Everything passes:

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:verify (verify) @ sample-webflux-mongodb ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:59 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-22T13:39:32-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've upgraded some dependencies, but there are no code changes between my project and what JHipster 7 beta 1 generates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wahoo! I fixed it.

The solution was to remove spring-security-data as a dependency.

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/c13bdc67aabcab76314a5540b2b82a29c81dd95c